# jquery button enable if checkbox and select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I enable the button if one or more checkbox is checked and if the select option of the checked checkbox is not equal to "no action"? Treating it as a row of table with checkbox being first element and select as last element?

This is how I am checking checkbox values.

```
<script>
  var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
      submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");


  submitButt.attr("disabled", "disabled");
  checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
  });
</script>
```

//dynamically generating rows

```
for ws in my_zones:
   html_output += \
        ''''<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" value="%s"/></td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>
            <select name="action">
                <option value='no action'>Choose Action</option>
                <option value='scan'>Reboot</option>
                <option value='swap'>Rebuild</option>
                <option value='terminate'>Terminate</option>

             </select></td></tr>''' \
        % (.......)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean custom select attribute?

Comment: i meant select tag in html.

Comment: I posted a possible solution, is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each check state change, verify what you want: if there at least one checkbox checked and if the "no action" checkbox is not checked. Then you can enable the submit button, or otherwise disable it.

```js
function updateSubmitButtonState(){
   
  var enableableLineCount= 0;
  $("tr").each(function(){
    if( isEnableableLine( this ) )
      enableableLineCount++;
  });
  
  if( enableableLineCount > 0 )
       $('[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled");
    else
       $('[type="submit"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
  
  
  function isEnableableLine( tr ){
  
    if( 
        $("input[type='checkbox']", tr).is(":checked") && 
        $("select option[value='no-action']:selected", tr ).length == 0 
    )
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
}

$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click",updateSubmitButtonState );
$("select").on("change",updateSubmitButtonState );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-group">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="option1">option 1 </option>
        <option value="option2">option 2 </option>
        <option value="no-action">no-action</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-group">
    </td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="option1">option 1 </option>
        <option value="option2">option 2 </option>
        <option value="no-action">no-action</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

**edit**

I have adapted the snippet to fit the goals described in coments. 
Now, at each change, the whole table is parsed. If there not hundred of line, it could be sufficient. But it is not very optimised.

Comment: thanks for the answer but last element is a select option not a checkbox. how to manage that?

Comment: i have updated my question with the snapshot and also with the structure of html. Since I am dynamically generating rows of the table, I am not thinking of using "id". Can we play without the "id"?

Comment: I tried to fit your example, but note that providing code may be more efficient.

Comment: As I understand, if there just one select which has an "no action" value, the submit button is disabled, is that right?

Comment: Because, you may be want that it is only if the select value of the checked line have a "no action" value which disable the submit button.

Comment: yes, so if each checkbox checked has selected option other than 'no action', i want to make the button visible else it will remain disabled. Also, button should be in disable mode after the page loading since all the checkboxes will be unchecked and "no action" would be the default option.

Comment: <script>   var submitButt = $("input[type='submit']"); submitButt.attr("disabled","disabled");    function updateSubmitButtonState(){
 
  var submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");
  if( 
        $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length > 0 && 
        $("select option[value='no-action']:selected").length == 0 
    )
       submitButt.removeAttr("disabled");
    else
       submitButt.attr("disabled","disabled");
 
}
.....
This I have done to make button disable during page loading which is keeping button disabled throughout even on right combinations. Is this the wrong way?

Comment: It is the wrong way if it is not what you want to achieve :)

Comment: see the update, you need to check all your table at each change. A better way could be to store the state of each line to know after eache change if there is always a line which can enable the submit button

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75614/discussion-between-user3089927-and-gael).

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/gzrv8v3q/13/

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");


submitButt.attr("disabled", "disabled");


$('#form1').change(function() {
    var disable = true
    if ( $('#select').val() != "no-action") {
        checkboxes.each(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                disable = false
            }
        })
    }
    submitButt.attr('disabled', disable);
})
```

Comment: if you have only one checkbox don't use each function

Comment: each row will have on checkbox..i have uploaded an image for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

The disabled attr must be deleted.  Even it existing makes it disabled.  I use: https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/

Also, your code will not add disabled back again if the checkbox is unchecked, also clarify if that is part of your question.

Comment: but i checked, checking and unchecking checkboxes and it is working fine..but then how to "&&"  "no action" select option with this.. just started with jquery.

Comment: That was the start of your question.